# .htaccess redirect ignore port

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ports

I have the following in my .htaccess to redirect non-www to www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.mysite\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine, but a visit to `www.mysite.com:8080` redirects to `www.mysite.com` removing the above lines from my .htaccess file results in the visit to port 8080 working.

So I know it is these two lines causing the issue.

I want to still have this affect, non-www redirected to www, but I want the redirect to maintain the port.

I have tried various versions of the above using `%{SERVER_PORT}` but had no luck, they either do not work or result in a redirect loop.

Thanks
Jake

**EDIT**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT 2**

I have now tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8080$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.mysite\.com:8080$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com:8080/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In an attempt to redirect a request on port 8080 to port 8080 again, this fails and redirects to `www.mysite.com` with no port. What does be useful would be just do nothing if the port is 8080, as this is only for testing and so I don't need to non-www/www redirect, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8080$
RewriteRule [Break here and do nothing more]
```

Comment: Did you also have no luck with something like `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8080$`? Also would you mind posting your current RewriteRules?

Comment: Other lines are now in an edit. These *ARE* the lines in question, because stripping it down to just these two lines results in the same behaviour.

Comment: Fabian, this `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8080$` would rewrite all ports to 8080? I need it to maintain the port, be it 80 or 8080 not rewrite all ports to 8080.

Comment: This RewriteCond says: **if the server port is 8080** then go to next line and perform e.g. a RewritRrule or check another RewriteCond. As the name says: it's a condition, not a rule

Comment: Thanks Fabian, I have added a new edit.

Comment: If you just don't want your current non-www to www rule to apply for server port 8080 try to add `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$` above. So it will do: **if server port is NOT 8080 perform my rule(s)**

Comment: Thanks Fabian, I have just tried that and it has not worked. Which makes me think that the request isn't even on 8080, which come to think of - it's not as its going through Varnish Cache. VC is on 8080, but that forwards onto Apache on 81, but `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` reads 80. I think I need to revisit the setup and work out where Apache is, as it should be on 81 and not 80. PHP thinks its on 80.

Comment: That came into my mind too, that there may be a problem with the ports itself. If you have any further questions don't mind to get back to me :) +1 for your question and posting edits!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here. But basically attempting to direct the port in .htaccess was not going to work.

I am using Varnish and wanting to manipulate the request, but because Varnish is on one port and Apache is on another it was hard to tell was is *actually* going on here.

In short I gave up.